# How do I configure apache for subdomains on pi in my own local network?

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, vs-web-site-project

I want to access multiple websites at home on my pi apache server, like this:

- projectA.localhost
- projectB.localhost

or :

- projectA.192.168.0.24  - IP of my pi.

I have tried to add vhost, but nothing has changed.
I can redirect my /var/www/ to other places but i want have a structur like:

/var/www/websites/projectA

/var/www/websites/projectB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this by modifying the hosts file on machines on my LAN that will access the server. That way, there is no special magic that has to occur in Apache (meaning that the web site can be moved to a public host without re-configuration.)

For example, configure Apache as typical with virtual hosts projecta.com and projectb.com (or projecta.localhost and projectb.localhost, if you prefer). There is no special Apache configuration on the server.

On the systems that will access projecta and projectb, configure the hosts file to point to the server's IP address:

projecta.com 192.168.0.24
projectb.com 192.168.0.24

-or-

projecta.localhost 192.168.0.24
projectb.localhost 192.168.0.24

Apache will properly route requests to the appropriate site.

Comment: Setting up Apache virtual hosts is well documented. I refer to this site often: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04 Then, modifying the hosts file on the systems accessing the Pi is easy enough. On Windows, the hosts file is located at C:\windows\system\drivers\etc\hosts on Linux, the hosts file is located at \etc\hosts.

Comment: So, that means i have to modify ever host file on my intern network so they can access to my page?

Comment: Not all of them - only the ones who need to access the projecta and projectb web sites. If every machine on your LAN will need access, then yes, you will have to modify the hosts file on every machine on your LAN. I don't know how you're going to map a name to an IP address without doing so, unless you have the ability to modify your DNS entries.

Comment: With the windows hosts, yes! Thanks. I tried to mark your answer as correct, but it won't work. It says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."